# Adding attachment to mail via msg.setContent(multipart) causes it not being sent anymore

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, attachment

I have code below for servlet program which is sending email to destined user. It is working fine till there is not attachment in the program but when i am attaching a file to it, then it is not delivering any email to destination.
 I have marked the line in program below---- msg.setContent(multipart), when i am setting content of message with multipart object then it is not triggering email otherwise it is working fine for mail with content only.

I am unable to understand where i am doing wrong, although i have updated my mail.jar to mail_1.4.jar and mail_1.5 jar and used attachFile() method as per updation in mail_1.4.jar.

```
String host = "asmtp.ccccs.com";
String to =  "abc@gmail.com";
String from =  "abc@gmail.com"; 
String subject ="hi";
String messageText ="yuppppp";
boolean sessionDebug = false;
// Create some properties and get the default Session.
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.host", host);
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

// Set debug on the Session
// Passing false will not echo debug info, and passing True will.

mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);

// Instantiate a new MimeMessage and fill it with the 
// required information.

Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
try{
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
msg.setText(messageText);
response.setContentType("text/html");
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


      BodyPart   messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

         // Fill the message
      //   messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");
         messageBodyPart.setContent(msg, "text/html");


          MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();  


         // Part two is attachment
         messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
         out.println("1");
         String filename = "C:/Users/Desktop/Conn.java";
         out.println("2");

         //String sigPath = context.getRealPath("/images/Discovery_email_sig.jpg");
         //  File sigFile = new File(sigPath);

         DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
         out.println("3");out.println(source);
         messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
         out.println("4");
         messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);
         out.println("5");

         messageBodyPart2.attachFile(filename);

         // Create a multipar message
         Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

         // Set text message part
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

         // Send the complete message parts
        msg.setContent(multipart);//// ----- When i am setting this, then email with attachment is not getting delievred

     out.println("7");
Transport.send(msg);
out.println("8");
out.println("Mail was sent to " + to);
out.println(" from " + from);
out.println(" using host " + host + ".");
}catch(Exception e){

out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Does it throw any exception? Replace `out.println(e);` in your catch block with `e.printStackTrace()` and add the eventual stack trace to the question. Anyway, mail is tricky, your code might work OK, but the e-mail could be "lost" on its way to the destination (e.g. refused by the spam filter).

Comment: @JozefChocholacek still not helping ....situation remains same man...no idea where i going wrong.....

Comment: Do you get any exception (i.e. do you see the "Mail was sent ..." message)? If you see the confirmation message, and no exception, then your code successfuly passes the e-mail message to the SMTP server. To debug, what happens next, you have to trace the SMTP server's log.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek no i didnt get any exception...program ran without sending mail...but on debug on my side i can trace that i doesnt reached transport.send(msg) line.

Comment: OK, so if the program didn't reach the `Transport.send(msg);` line, what has actually happened? Did you debug it line by line in an IDE?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek thanks buddy for the help..its working....actually i missed creating multipart and body part to that...                               Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 
       multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);    ....i addded and it is working fine with java_1.3.jar standards